# Finding the inverse of a mod

Tags: modular-arithmetic

How come $5^{-1} \pmod{2436} = 1949$? What are the steps to calculate it?

This is what I tried:

$5 \cdot I = 1 \pmod{2436}$

Comment: Do you know extended Euclidean algorithm?

Answer (score 1):

Observe that

$$5\cdot1949=9745=4\cdot2436+1\implies1949=5^{-1}\pmod{2436}$$

**Added** . In this particular case it can be very easy: observe that

$$2436=2435+1=487\cdot5+1\implies487\cdot5=-1+2436=-1\pmod{2436}\implies$$

$$\implies(-487)\cdot5=1\pmod{2436}$$

and since $\;-487=1949\pmod{2436}\;$ , we've finished.

Comment: How do I get the value if I'm asked to find 5^-1(mod2436) ? I can't guess 1949?

Comment: @user11 You didn't ask "how", you asked "why" and that's what I addressed. The how can be very hard, but I might give it a try and add that to my answer in a few minutes more.

Comment: It can't be very hard, it's just Euclid's algorithm. But it can be quite long for big numbers (but not too long either, it's a pretty efficient algorithm).

Comment: @CaptainLama Thank you, When I wrote hard I meant by hand. Try to do it for moderately big numbers (say, in the tens of thousands) with some different, realtively high prime divisors, and it can take a quite while...provided you don't make any arithmetical mistake. Just like calculating a 5x5 or 6x5 determinant with numbers that can't easily be factored or something like that: it can be pretty long a hard-working.

Comment: Above it is $\;6\times6\;$, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a general method for finding the inverse of $a$ in $Z_n$:

- Set $x_1=1$
- Set $x_2=0$
- Set $y_1=0$
- Set $y_2=1$
- Set $r_1=n$
- Set $r_2=a$
- Repeat until $r_2=0$:

  - Set $r_3=r_1\bmod{r_2}$
  - Set $q_3=r_1/r_2$
  - Set $x_3=x_1-q_3\cdot{x_2}$
  - Set $y_3=y_1-q_3\cdot{y_2}$
  - Set $x_1=x_2$
  - Set $x_2=x_3$
  - Set $y_1=y_2$
  - Set $y_2=y_3$
  - Set $r_1=r_2$
  - Set $r_2=r_3$
- If $y_1>0$ then output $y_1$, otherwise output $y_1+n$

---

And here is an equivalent code in C:

```
int Inverse(int n,int a)
{
    int x1 = 1;
    int x2 = 0;
    int y1 = 0;
    int y2 = 1;
    int r1 = n;
    int r2 = a;

    while (r2 != 0)
    {
        int r3 = r1%r2;
        int q3 = r1/r2;
        int x3 = x1-q3*x2;
        int y3 = y1-q3*y2;

        x1 = x2;
        x2 = x3;
        y1 = y2;
        y2 = y3;
        r1 = r2;
        r2 = r3;
    }

    return y1>0? y1:y1+n;
}
```

Calling `Inverse(2436,5)` returns $1949$.